# Where do I ask a question about W3C standards and their status?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wanted to know what some of the W3C standards meant from here,

https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/components#w3c_all

and Web Components.  But I don't know where to ask it.  Where should I ask it?

Comment: @rene without knowing more specifics this seems to be [rather slippery advice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

Comment: Frankly, I'd be most inclined to go back to the source. Have you looked at https://www.w3.org/participate/ to see if they have a discussion list/group that is appropriate to your needs?